# JSON.stringify(input) returning undefined

Tags: angular

I am writing service to call my cloud function api which is deployed. I am not sure what has happened because the previous services that i wrote for user are working just fine and even the JSON.stringify is changing the data to json perfectly but now i have created the service for a new module in the same way as the previous one  but in this service json.stringigy is not working and returning me undefined. I am also seeing this error in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of undefined

Here is my code for service

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductAddonServiceProxy {
    private http: HttpClient;
    private baseUrl: string;
    protected jsonParseReviver: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined = undefined;

    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient, @Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "";
    }

    AddAddonData(input: AddAddonDto | null | undefined): Observable<void> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "https://us-central1-donskybackend.cloudfunctions.net/xxxxxx";
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

        const content_ = JSON.stringify(input);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
        let options_: any = {
            body: content_,
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            })
        };

        return this.http.request("post", url_, options_).mergeMap((response_: any) => {
            return this.processAddAddonData(response_);
        }).catch((response_: any) => {
            if(response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
                return this.processAddAddonData(<any>response_);
            }
            // if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            //     try {
            //         return this.processAddProfile(<any>response_);
            //     } catch (e) {
            //         return <Observable<void>><any>Observable.throwError(e);
            //     }
            // } else
            //     return <Observable<void>><any>Observable.throwError(response_);
        });
    }

    protected processAddAddonData(response: HttpResponseBase): Observable<void> {

        const status = response.status;
        const responseBlob =
            response instanceof HttpResponse ? response.body :
                (<any>response).error instanceof Blob ? (<any>response).error : undefined;

        let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers) { for (let key of response.headers.keys()) { _headers[key] = response.headers.get(key); } };
        if (status === 200) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).mergeMap(_responseText => {
                let result200: any = null;
                let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
                return Observable.of(resultData200);
            });
        } else if (status === 401) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).mergeMap(_responseText => {
                return throwException("A server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            });
        } else if (status === 403) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).mergeMap(_responseText => {
                return throwException("A server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            });
        } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).mergeMap(_responseText => {
                return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            });
        }
        return Observable.of<void>(<any>null);
    }
}
```

This is what i am sending in input

```
AddAddonDto {options: true, code: "90878", prodname: "Hello Product", price: "400", description: "dfg dgdsfgds ", …}
```

Take a look at [image: this] picture

Comment: Whats the output of `console.log(input)` in AddAddonData function.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 that output is added in the end if the code. `AddAddonDto {options: true, code: "90878", prodname: "Hello Product", price: "400", description: "dfg dgdsfgds ", …}`

Comment: but JSON.stringify on input gives me undefined

Comment: I don't think input variable has `{options: true, code: "90878", prodname: "Hello Product", price: "400", description: "dfg dgdsfgds "}` kind of data. I checked it and this data works perfectly. Can you check sending data and console.log output are same ?

Comment: FIrst do input.toString()
and then JSON.Stingify()

Comment: In component this is what i did now `console.log("Sending Data from Component", this.addon);` and it returned me this `Sending Data from Component AddAddonDto {options: true, code: "90878", prodname: "Hello Product", price: "400", description: "Hewj;sfoisj kh iuj kh iuhk o hjo"}`
In service this what i write now `console.log("Reached in service here: ", input);` and got this `Reached in service here:  AddAddonDto {options: true, code: "90878", prodname: "Hello Product", price: "400", description: "Hewj;sfoisj kh iuj kh iuhk o hjo", …}
`

Comment: Try adding quotes to everything like this: `{"options":"true", "code":"90878", ... }`

Comment: Can you please check TYPE OF input ?

Comment: @SamiHK type of input is an object of Dto Class

Comment: @OrestisZekai if i add quotes then it will already be in json format, wouldn't it?

Comment: Data contains Type name. It should be removed. `AddAddonDto {options: true, code: "90878", prodname: "Hello Product", price: "400", description: "Hewj;sfoisj kh iuj kh iuhk o hjo", …}` should be `{options: true, code: "90878", prodname: "Hello Product", price: "400", description: "Hewj;sfoisj kh iuj kh iuhk o hjo", …}`

Comment: @ranjeet8082 i am unable to find any difference between the two outputs you put here. where is my data containing type name? can you please tell me more?

Comment: `AddAddonDto ` should be removed from data. After that data will be `{options: true, code: "90878", prodname: "Hello Product", price: "400", description: "Hewj;sfoisj kh iuj kh iuhk o hjo", …}`.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 as i mentioned in the question explanation that it working fine for user service and that service is designed in the same way as this one.

Comment: JSON.stringify() accepts an object having key value pairs within curly brackets {}. Anything outside curly {} will give error.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 i edited my question with a picture take a look at it. AddUserDto worked fine but AddAddonData did not